# ASP NET CORE GetConnectionString doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-core, connection-string, dbcontext

I'm new to ASP NET CORE and I'm writing new web API. I'm not able to retrieve connection string from the appsettings.json file and I get an 
ArgumentNullException.
This is the code in my Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDBConnection")));
        ...
    }
}
```

This is my appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDBConnection": "..."
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
       "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Warning"
       }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:
This is also my Program.cs class:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Comment: Your code looks good to me, the only thing I would change is to call services.AddMvc() after services.AddDbContext (in fact after any other service registration).

Comment: I put it at the end, after other service registartion, but nothing changes

Comment: @NicolasP Then there is something wrong in anywhere. Can you give remote access with team viewer so that I can fix this.

Comment: I think the problem is Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() which might cause issues debug and make sure that the path is the correct one.

Comment: @AntoniosKatopodis yes, it is. I removed it and now seems that it works, thanks!

Comment: To check whether it is related with `InProcess` and `OutOfProcess`. refer [ASP.NET Core Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2), and check the available workaround [In-Process hosting Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() location #4206](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4206)

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer this. `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` will get the bin/debug or release location.

This means that it will not be the project location. So it can not find the application.json and also it would also not be able to find your MVC views later on.